# Run ipython notebook server without new terminal option

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm running ipython notebook 3.2.1 on heroku with a pgcontents backend; essentially per this: https://github.com/mietek/instant-ipython

I can see that there is an option to launch a new terminal from the `new` menu in the top right of the landing page.

Is there a way to disable this option via the NotebookApp config (or similar)?  I would prefer not to give my end users this option - I can't find where to do this in the docs ...

We will be upgrading to the latest jupyter build in the next few months, so any advice on how to this on the latest version would also be appreciated.

thank you !

Comment: If you ensure that it can't import the `terminado` Python package, terminals will not be available. Bear in mind that this isn't a security measure, though - anything users can do in a terminal, they can also do in a notebook.

Comment: @ThomasK yep agree - still getting my head around the limitations. Is it possible stop the notebook running terminal like commands ?

Comment: Not easily, and you can do the same operations (like reading or deleting files) from Python code anyway. If you want to protect the system from the users, it's generally better to run the notebook in a container or some environment which doesn't have anything important for people to misuse.